# How to get binary data for video file in javascript, Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http, filereader

I am using ionic 3 platform for uploading a video file to vimeo api. I need to get binary data for video file and I am uploading using input type file element.

The code I have written is as follow

```
  videoUploadBody(videoObj) {
    const r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(){
        console.log("Binary data", r.result);
        return r.result;
    };
    r.readAsArrayBuffer(videoObj);
  }
```

This is the function that I need to call and it should return me video file in binary form. The function from where I am calling above function is as follow

```
 uploadVideo(videoFile, createdVideo) : Observable<any> {
    const bodyObj = this.compilerProvider.videoUploadBody(videoFile);
    return this.http.patch<Observable<any>>(createdVideo.upload.upload_link, bodyObj, this.uploadReqOpts);
  }
```

Here the bodyObj variable contains undefined, whereas I have console.log is videoUploadBody function gives me data in binary form.

I think there is some async or promise issue. What do I need to change to get back binary data in uploadVideo function?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that it is a promise issue. In your first function, `r.onload` will only return after the first function returns, and even then it will only return from the nested function.

I'm not going to write the correct code for you, but what you have to do is wrap the first function's body in a promise that resolves within the `r.onload` function, then the second function should call `.then` on that promise to operate on it (hint: you'll need to make another promise here).

MDN has good information about `Promise`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise